# Starts with doesn't work in Linq to NHibernate query

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, startswith

In my repository I have:

```
public IQueryable<ICustomer> GetByAddress(string address)
{
    return from c in GetSession().Linq<ICustomer>()
           where c.Address.StartsWith(address)
           select c;
}
```

The SQL I'd like it to generate is essentially:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE address LIKE @address + '%'
```

However, whenever I do

```
var customers = myRepository.GetByAddress("123 Main Street");
```

I get a NullReferenceException:

> > System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
> >       Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
> >       Source="NHibernate"
> >       StackTrace:
> >            at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetEntityName(ICriteria subcriteria, String propertyName)
> >            at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetColumns(String propertyName, ICriteria subcriteria)
> >            at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.GetColumnsUsingProjection(ICriteria subcriteria, String propertyName)
> >     Snip...

I have snipped the rest of the exception because it is quite verbose, if it would be helpful I can add it.

Why does this not work, while the exact same query except with

```
where c.Address == address
```

works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

I'm using FluentNHibernate (where Id is a GUID and Address is a string):

```
public class CustomerMap: ClassMap<ICustomer>
{
    public JobMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        ...snip...
        Map(x => x.Address).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this *should* work with the 2.x linq provider, I have examples of .StartsWith restrictions that translate to the correct SQL in my project.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the newest build of the nhcontrib linq provider?

Comment: I have version 2.1.2 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/

Comment: I'll remove my references, and delete the dll's and then redownload to ensure that I've got the latest ones

Comment: You can see that it is indeed supported by the provider: http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Linq/src/NHibernate.Linq/Visitors/WhereArgumentsVisitor.cs?revision=1304&view=markup so it has to have something to do with your usage...